# Compare two DataTable Rows remove identical rows besides one.

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check the rows of two data tables. If there is an exact match I want to remove all but one.

I've figured out how to compare two rows of data. I'm not sure the best way to return the cleaned up version without duplicates.

the tables within my program are pulling tables from a database, so i simplified them for the example.

Here's what I've worked out so far.

```
 var table1 = new list<string>();
 var table2 = new list<string>();

foreach (DataRow row1 in table.Rows)
                foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
                {
                    var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
                    var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

                    if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
                    {
                        // store the unique elements within a new list?
                        // remove duplicates and return the remainder?
                    }
                }
```

I thought using the Intersect() method might be an option as well.

Comment: A DataView has a method ToTable that will give you distinct rows. Can you use that instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Cast to a hashset of your desired type. They will automatically remove duplicates, as by definition hashset cannot have duplicate entries. 
More info:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset